# How to make GridSplitter to resize non-adjacent rows?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have following layout:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="4" />
        <RowDefinition Height="20" MinHeight="20" MaxHeight="20" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" ResizeDirection="Rows" Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <DockPanel Grid.Row="2" x:Name="toolbox" Background="Chocolate" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
</Grid>
```

How to make grid splitter to adjust size between rows 0 and 3?

Comment: I think the best solution here would be to make your Row Heights all either `Auto` or `*`. Then then sizing would be handled the best. Rather give your controls a specific height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Background="Blue"
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="4" Background="Red"
                  ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" ResizeDirection="Rows"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <DockPanel Grid.Row="2" Height="20" x:Name="toolbox" Background="Chocolate" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Background="Blue"
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="SkyBlue" />
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="4" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" ResizeDirection="Rows" Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <Grid Grid.Row="2">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DockPanel Grid.Row="0" Height="20" x:Name="toolbox" Background="Chocolate" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Green" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a grid in grid.

```
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="4" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" ResizeDirection="Rows" Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <DockPanel Grid.Row="0" Height="20"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
```